# Odd issue for large Fibonacci loops

Tags: python

This code work well to get the sum of Fibonacci (with extra conditions):

```
def sumFibs(num):
  fb=[0,1]
  while fb[-1] <= num: #even with : for i in range(1,num) it didn't work!
    fb.append(fb[-1] + fb[-2])
  r=[i for i in fb if i%2!=0 and i<num]
  return sum(r)
```

but if the given number is 75024 and 75025 ,the result will be the same (60696) !!!

Comment: That's because the Fibonacci series sums the last two numbers, and as the series goes, the numbers become big, so the difference of 1 is insignificant in this case.

Comment: Actually, all your results comes in pair of two i.e `sumFibs(2)==sumFibs(3)` and `sumFibs(4)==sumFibs(5)`

Comment: @CutePoison, nope: `i` is a fibonacci term, not its rank. for 2 and 3, and for 4 and 5 it happens to work because it consider only odd fib terms (so 1,3,5,13,21,55,89,233,...). So for small `i`, because of the `1,3,5` start, it looks like all odd number are boundaries. `sumFibs(0)==sumFibs(1)`, `sumFibs(2)==sumFibs(3)`, `sumFibs(4)==sumFibs(5)`. But then, rule changes: `sumFibs(6)==sumFibs(7)==sumFibs(8)==sumFibs(9)==sumFibs(10)==sumFibs(11)==sumFibs(12)==sumFibs(13)`, then `sumFibs(14)==...==sumFibs(21)`, `sumFibs(22)==…=sumFibs(55)`, `sumFibs(56)==…==sumFibs(89)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because your loop continues even after the last Fibonacci number exceeds num. As a result, it adds the next Fibonacci number to the fb list, which is greater than num. Then, the filter operation 'i <= num' in the list comprehension excludes this extra number, leading to incorrect results for numbers like 75024 and 75025.

To fix the issue, you should modify the while loop condition to stop before exceeding num, rather than including the first Fibonacci number that exceeds num.

Code:

```
def sumFibs(num):
    fb = [0, 1]
    while fb[-1] + fb[-2] <= num:
        fb.append(fb[-1] + fb[-2])
    r = [i for i in fb if i % 2 != 0 and i <= num]
    return sum(r)

print(sumFibs(75024))  # Output: 60696
print(sumFibs(75025))  # Output: 135721
```

Comment: updated as 'i <= num' in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing what you think you are doing. At least I am pretty sure you think `num` is the term index. Hence the reason why you expect `sumFibs(75024)` to be different than `sumFibs(75025)`. Hence the reason why you've mentionned in comment a for loop (which would be a very different thing)

What that `num` is, is the maximum possible term value to sum. Not the number of computed terms.

Since the 23th, 24th, 25th, 26th and 27th terms of Fibonacci are 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393 and 196418 it is therefore normal that Σfib(i) is the same ∀x∈(28658, 46368), then another common value ∀x∈(46369, 75025), another for (75026, 121393) another for (121394, 196418), etc.

And since, further more, you sum only odd terms, and therefore consider only terms 23, 25 and 26 (among those) of fib serie, constant interval for `sumFibs(x)` are `(28658, 75025)`, `(75026, 121393)`, ...

See

```
sumFibs(28657) → 32039
sumFibs(28658) → 60696
sumFibs(28659) → 60696
sumFibs(75025) → 60696
sumFibs(75026) → 135721
sumFibs(121393)→ 135721
sumFibs(121394)→ 257114
```